# Refactoring RadioGroup setter code?

Tags: java, android

I am setting different `RadioGroup` like this:

```
fragment.setT1RadioGroup((RadioGroup)fragView.findViewById(rowids[0]).findViewById(R.id.t1_radiogroup));
fragment.setT2RadioGroup((RadioGroup)fragView.findViewById(rowids[1]).findViewById(R.id.t1_radiogroup));
fragment.setT3RadioGroup((RadioGroup)fragView.findViewById(rowids[2]).findViewById(R.id.t1_radiogroup));
fragment.setT4RadioGroup((RadioGroup)fragView.findViewById(rowids[3]).findViewById(R.id.t1_radiogroup));
fragment.setT5RadioGroup((RadioGroup)fragView.findViewById(rowids[4]).findViewById(R.id.t1_radiogroup));
fragment.setT6RadioGroup((RadioGroup)fragView.findViewById(rowids[5]).findViewById(R.id.t1_radiogroup));
fragment.setT7RadioGroup((RadioGroup)fragView.findViewById(rowids[6]).findViewById(R.id.t1_radiogroup));
fragment.setT8RadioGroup((RadioGroup)fragView.findViewById(rowids[7]).findViewById(R.id.t1_radiogroup));
fragment.setT9RadioGroup((RadioGroup)fragView.findViewById(rowids[8]).findViewById(R.id.t1_radiogroup));
fragment.setT10RadioGroup((RadioGroup)fragView.findViewById(rowids[9]).findViewById(R.id.t1_radiogroup));
```

For refactoring purpose could I reduce the size of this code? How?

Comment: Show us your code for whatever the `fragment` object is. In what way is the `fragment.setT1RadioGroup` different from `fragment.setT2RadioGroup`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that `setT5RadioGroup` only sets a variable within the fragment:

In your fragment, use `RadioGroup[] radioGroups = new RadioGroup[10];`

```
setTRadioGroup(int number, RadioGroup grp) {
   this.radioGroups[number] = grp;
}
```

In your activity, or whatever it is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowids.length; i++) { // assuming rowids.length is 10
    RadioGroup grp = (RadioGroup)fragView.findViewById(rowids[i]).findViewById(R.id.t1_radiogroup);
    fragment.setTRadioGroup(i, grp);
}
```

Whenever you find yourself using multiple numbered methods that does very similar things, think: **Array!!** (or possibly `List<ElementType>` if you want to be able to add/remove dynamically)