# How to reduce this RadioGroup Code?

Tags: java, android

I have 18 `RadioGroup`. I am declaring the `RadioGroup` like this way

```
private RadioGroup kn1RadioGroup, kn2RadioGroup, kn4aRadioGroup,
kn4bRadioGroup, kn4cRadioGroup, kn4dRadioGroup, kn4eRadioGroup,
kn4fRadioGroup, kn4gRadioGroup, kn4hRadioGroup, kn4iRadioGroup,kn4jRadioGroup,ap2aRadioGroup,ap2bRadioGroup,
ap2cRadioGroup,ap2dRadioGroup,ap2eRadioGroup,pr1RadioGroup;
```

I have created getter and setter for these `RadioGroup`. And I am setting the RadioGroup id like this way

```
fragment.setKn1RadioGroup((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.kn1_radio_group));
fragment.setKn2RadioGroup((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.kn2_radio_group));
fragment.setPr1RadioGroup((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.pr1_radio_group));     
fragment.setKn4aRadioGroup((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.kn4a_radio_group));
fragment.setKn4bRadioGroup((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.kn4b_radio_group));
fragment.setKn4cRadioGroup((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.kn4c_radio_group));
fragment.setKn4dRadioGroup((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.kn4d_radio_group));
fragment.setKn4eRadioGroup((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.kn4e_radio_group));
fragment.setKn4fRadioGroup((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.kn4f_radio_group));
fragment.setKn4gRadioGroup((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.kn4g_radio_group));
fragment.setKn4hRadioGroup((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.kn4h_radio_group));
fragment.setKn4iRadioGroup((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.kn4i_radio_group));
fragment.setKn4jRadioGroup((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.kn4j_radio_group));       
fragment.setAp2aRadioGroup((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.ap2a_radio_group));
fragment.setAp2bRadioGroup((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.ap2b_radio_group));
fragment.setAp2cRadioGroup((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.ap2c_radio_group));
fragment.setAp2dRadioGroup((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.ap2d_radio_group));
fragment.setAp2eRadioGroup((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.ap2e_radio_group));
```

Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: So...can you explain why this question is different [to your previous one](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39468/refactoring-radiogroup-setter-code)?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to define a constant integer array holding the ids:

```
private static final int[] ids = { R.id.kn1_radio_group, R.id.kn2_radio_group, R.id.pr1_radio_group, /* and so on... */};
```

And then using the same method as in my answer to [your previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39468/refactoring-radiogroup-setter-code).

However, your naming of these RadioGroups tells me that there **might be another structure here.** And I also suspect that there is more to your application than what we see here. So what you really should do is to **think about the structure of your variables;** Should a `kn` be a class? Should `kn4` be an array on it's own, or should perhaps `kn` be a two-dimensional array (one dimension for the number and one for the letter. **These are questions that none of us currently can answer considering the lack of context we have about your application**. If you would explain a bit more about **What your application is for** and what a `kn` / `ap` RadioGroup is, then we might help you more. You probably have some reasons for naming the radio groups the way that you do, in which case a different structure than an array might be more useful.

Also, I would like to add something: Why not let the fragment take care of it's own initialization of the RadioGroups? Is perhaps the RadioGroups a part of the fragment's view already? If so, then there is no need to use all these setter methods for it.